# Android camera: stopPreview vs releaseCamera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am making an application where I have a camera inside of a viewPager. I am wondering what would best be suited to "pause" and "resume" the camera so it doesn't hog resources when it is pre-loaded. I have the feeling that stopPreview is better suited for this as it does not release the camera but keeps it however it doesn't display the camera which is the main reason it hogs resources.

- Enter & exit application: startCamera() & releaseCamera()
- Tab visible & not visible: startPreview() & stop Preview()

Would this be a good rule of thumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes care of most of the operations `CameraPreview.java`:

```
package com.example.fela;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.ErrorCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.List;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Camera camera;
    private int cameraId;
    private Activity activity;
    private CameraPreviewActivityInterface activityInterface;

    public CameraPreview(Activity activity, int cameraId) {
        super(activity);
        try {
            activityInterface = (CameraPreviewActivityInterface) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement ExampleFragmentCallbackInterface ");
        }
        this.activity = activity;
        this.cameraId = cameraId;
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {}

    /**
     * custom camera tweaks and startPreview()
     */
    public void refreshCamera() {
        if (holder.getSurface() == null || camera == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist, camera not opened created yet
            return;
        }
        Log.i(null, "CameraPreview refreshCamera()");
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        int rotation = ((WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        // specifically for back facing camera
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(degrees);
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // this error is fixed in the camera Error Callback (Error 100)
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }



    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.i(null, "CameraPreview surfaceChanged()");
        // if your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        // do not start the camera if the tab isn't visible
        if(activityInterface.getCurrentPage() == 1)
            startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}

    public Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = Camera.open();
        // parameters for camera
        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.set("jpeg-quality", 100);
        params.set("iso", "auto");
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        // set the image dimensions
        List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        int max = 0, width = 0, height = 0;
        for(Size size : sizes) {
            if(max < (size.width*size.height)) {
                max = (size.width*size.height);
                width = size.width;
                height = size.height;
            }
        }
        params.setPictureSize(width, height);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        // primarily used to fix Error 100
        camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
                if(error == Camera.CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {
                    releaseCamera();
                    startCamera();
                }
            }
        });
        return camera;
    }

    /**
     * intitialize a new camera
     */
    protected void startCamera() {
        if(getCamera() == null)
            setCamera(getCameraInstance());
        refreshCamera();
    }

    /**
     * release camera so other applications can utilize the camera
     */
    protected void releaseCamera() {
        // if already null then the camera has already been released before
        if (getCamera() != null) {
            getCamera().release();
            setCamera(null);
        }
    }

    public Camera getCamera() {
        return camera;
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        this.camera = camera;
    }

    public void setCameraId(int cameraId) {
        this.cameraId = cameraId;
    }

    /**
     * get the current viewPager page
     */
    public interface CameraPreviewActivityInterface {
        public int getCurrentPage();
    }
}
```

In my `FragmentCamera.java` file:

```
private CameraPreview cameraPreview;

// code...

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // code...
    cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), cameraId);
    previewLayout.addView(cameraPreview);
    // code...
}

// code...

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    cameraPreview.releaseCamera();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    cameraPreview.startCamera();
}

protected void fragmentVisible() {
    onResume();
}

protected void fragmentNotVisible() {
    onPause();
}
```

And the MainActivity.java file (implements CameraPreviewActivityInterface):

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        currentPage = position;
        if (currentPage == 1) {
            fragmentCamera.fragmentVisible();
        } else {
            fragmentCamera.fragmentNotVisible();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});

@Override
public int getCurrentPage() {
    return currentPage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. :

If I kept camera (in ViewPager) in on state, the swipe were clunky and OOM exceptions were frequent.

Two options came in my mind:

shift the entire instance in a different thread

OR

use stopPreview() and startPreview()

I went with the second one :

However, instead of doing this on Fragment lifecycle callbacks I gave a button on the fragment which toggled the preview. Reason being, if user is swiping very fast, you can still receive OOm exception since the preview calls will be queued, especially if there are very few fragments in the viewPager.

In essence Release camera onPause(), acquire camera in onResume() and give a groovy button in fragment which will toggle your Preview on the surface!

Comment: About the fast swiping, forgot totally about that. +1

Comment: glad to help. Let me know what you went with!

Answer (score 1):

Hello Karl I had the same things need to implement in view pager. I have circular viewer in which one fragment has the camera fragment. I want to handle the camera preview in such a way so it should not consume the camera resource.

As you know android view pager default load two fragment in to the memory. We implemented the view pager change listener and call the fragment method to start and stop the preview. even also destroy the camera preview in on destroy method of fragment.

```
class ViewPagerChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        int currentPosition = DEFAULT_FRAGMENT;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            TimberLogger.d(TAG, "onPageScrollStateChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int index, float arg1, int arg2) {
            TimberLogger.d(TAG, "onPageScrolled" + index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mWatchPosition = position;
            TimberLogger.d(TAG, "onPageSelected" + mWatchPosition);

            int newPosition = 0;
            if (position > 4) {
                newPosition = position;
            }

            TimberLogger.d(TAG, "newPosition" + newPosition);

            /**
             * Listener knows the new position and can call the interface method
             * on new Fragment with the help of PagerAdapter. We can here call
             * onResumeFragment() for new fragment and onPauseFragment() on the
             * current one.
             */

            // new fragment onResume
            loadedFragment(newPosition).onResumeFragment();

            // current fragment onPuase called
            loadedFragment(currentPosition).onPauseFragment();

            currentPosition = newPosition;

            TimberLogger.d(TAG, "currentPosition" + currentPosition);
        }
    }
```

See the two method onResumeFragment and onPuaseFragment this two are the custom function each view pager fragment implements. In view pager change event we call the pause of current fragment and onResume of the new fragment.

```
// new fragment onResume
 loadedFragment(newPosition).onResumeFragment();

 // current fragment onPuase called
 loadedFragment(currentPosition).onPauseFragment();
```

You can write your camera start preview inside custom method onResumeFragment and  stop preview in onPauseFragment and also make sure you should override the onDestory() method of your camera fragment for release the camera resources.

Comment: You got me on the right path, I have a very nice solution which I will post!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to startCamera() in onResume(), and release it in onPause(), so you can handle, that camera is not free in onResume(). 
In ViewPager you can startPreview(), when fragment with it is selected, and stopPreview() otherwise. Also u can startPreview() in onCreateView() and  stopPreview() in onDestroyView() in fragment.