# Take picture with flash doesn't work

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a service that takes picture in the background... This service works in three modes:

1. Front cam
2. Back cam
3. Back cam with flash

The first two work great, however when enabling flash to Camera parameters, no image is returned in the "Camera.PictureCallback"...
In fact the callback is never triggered.

The flash fires and everything seems OK, but no image is received.

This is my onStartCommand :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    try {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
        params.width = 1;
        params.height = 1;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;
        sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());

        windowManager.addView(sv, params);
        SurfaceHolder sHolder = sv.getHolder();
        sHolder.addCallback(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

This is my Camera initialization code:

```
                myCamera = Camera.open();

                if (myCamera != null) {
                    myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
                    Camera.Parameters parameters = myCamera.getParameters();

                    parameters.setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE_ON);
                    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
                    parameters.setJpegQuality(70);

                    // set camera parameters
                    myCamera.setParameters(parameters);

                    myCamera.startPreview();
                    myCamera.setErrorCallback(errorCallBack);
                    myCamera.takePicture(mShutter, null, mCall);
               }
```

Comment: If it is then you might want to set the flash mode to : FLASH_MODE_ON instead of FLASH_MODE_AUTO.

Comment: Yes, the code is called...
"FLASH_MODE" is a variable set from bundle extras... and it is set to "FLASH_MODE_ON" when enabling flash

Comment: I have 3 cases:
Front Cam (FLASH_MODE_OFF) - Main Cam (FLASH_MODE_AUTO) - Main+Flash (FLASH_MODE_ON)

Comment: Did that edit not effect your issue? The flash is still not working? What kind of device are you working on?

Comment: No, same issue....
Huawei m8 and another OEM device

Comment: @Abudzaid ::  I have been testing other devices and I have come upon several devices which respond differently to the Flash Mode settings. I've even upgraded to the Camera2 API with no improvement. Depending on the device and the settings I use I will get a flash every time, get only one for the first capture or no flash for any capture. This seems to vary device to device.

Comment: @Barns52 :: First, thanks a lot for your assistance... I believe you are right, I also got different responses from different devices, and I can't find a solution that works for them all.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code and it is working on Samsung Galaxy 6, 7; Moto G4, LG (I can't remember the model).

```
    public void onMyClick(View v){
        startTakingPictures();
    }


    private void startTakingPictures() {
        try {
            android.hardware.Camera cam = android.hardware.Camera.open();
            if (cam != null) {

                int presentOrientation  = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

                SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(getBaseContext());
                cam.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
                Camera.Parameters para = cam.getParameters();

                para.setRotation(ORIENTATIONS.get(presentOrientation));
                para.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
//                Log.e(TAG, "lat lng == " + loc.getLatitude());
//                para.setGpsLatitude(loc.getLatitude());
//                para.setGpsLongitude(loc.getLongitude());
                cam.setParameters(para);

                cam.startPreview();
                cam.takePicture(null, null, getJpegCallBack());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Camera.PictureCallback getJpegCallBack() {
        Camera.PictureCallback jpg = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream fos;

                String path = getPathBaseName();
                if(path.isEmpty()){
                    return;
                }

                path = "image.jpg";
                Log.e(TAG, "Image path == " + path);

                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };
        return jpg;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

**Since `Camera` is now depreciated you might want to implement `android.hardware.camera2`.**

It appears you are having an issue with the type of parameters your device can support. Take a look at the available flash parameters:

```
Camera.Parameters para = cam.getParameters();    
    for(String s : para.getSupportedFlashModes()){
        Log.e(TAG, "Supported Flash Mode =  " + s);
    }
```

you might need to set the flash mode like this:

```
param.set("flash-mode", "on");
cam.setParameters(param);
```

In addition to that, you might want to check-out the implementation by Karl Morrison in this post:
[Android camera: stopPreview vs releaseCamera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166574/android-camera-stoppreview-vs-releasecamera)

Comment: I used this code... (Same issue)... It works fine on No_Flash_Mode...
However when enabling flash, the device hangs after takePicture() method.
at the stopPreview().. and camera device freezes.. Even main camera app can't start and use camera.

It gives an error: "Camera resource is not free, please close the app....etc"

Comment: In the code I posted there is no `stopPreview()` method.  Sadly I cannot replicate your issue. I use this code in a loop and it takes a picture every 3 second with no issues. Could you post your logcat of the error?